# Sqoop import --as-parquetfile from Oracle gets wrong file types

Tags: database, oracle, sqoop, cloudera-cdh, parquet

I am using CDH 5.5 with Sqoop 1.4.6 and Hive 1.2.1 (which I manually downloaded to get the Parquet support for additional data types)

Here is the import command I'm using:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@database:port:name --username username --password password --table SHARE_PROPERTY -m 1 --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N'  --hive-import --hive-table SHARE_PROPERTY --as-parquetfile --compression-codec snappy --map-column-hive "CREATE_DATE=String"
```

The command successfully completes, and when I describe the table in Hive I see:

```
hive> describe share_property;
OK
share_property_id       string                                      
customer_id             string                                      
website_user_id         string                                      
address_id              string                                      
listing_num             string                                      
source                  string                                      
is_facebook             string                                      
is_twitter              string                                      
is_linkedin             string                                      
is_email                string                                      
create_date             string                                      
Time taken: 1.09 seconds, Fetched: 11 row(s)
```

Most of these fields are actually Oracle `NUMBER` types, and are imported as `double` if I stop trying to import a parquet file and just use the default text file.  The create_date field is a DATE in Oracle, and is sometimes imported as a bigint, and sometimes as a string depending on the command I use.

In any case, when I try to query this data in Hive, I run into this error:

```
hive> select * from share_property limit 20;
OK
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/parquet-format-2.1.0-cdh5.5.1.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/parquet-pig-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.5.1.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.5.1.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [shaded.parquet.org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: parquet.schema.Types$MessageTypeBuilder.addFields([Lparquet/schema/Type;)Lparquet/schema/Types$GroupBuilder;
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.DataWritableReadSupport.getSchemaByName(DataWritableReadSupport.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.DataWritableReadSupport.init(DataWritableReadSupport.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.getSplit(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator$FetchInputFormatSplit.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:673)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:445)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:140)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Obviously the data is not being imported correctly, or parquet is having trouble.  If I import as a text file I can successfully query the data (as long as I set `--map-column-hive CREATE_DATE=String`, otherwise it imports as a long), but if I try to insert that data into a parquet table to convert the formats, it also errors out.  So maybe the error is there?  I've tried manually setting all of the column types with `--map-column-hive` and `--map-column-java`, but that doesn't seem to help either

In addition, I've found documentation saying that Sqoop supports importing the Oracle `DATE` type, and that Parquet supports Date/Timestamp, but I can't get it to successfully import as either one (using `--map-column-hive` or `--map-column-java` or `-Doraoop.timestamp.string=false` with the `--direct` option)

I get the feeling that there's some documentation that I'm missing or just can't find.  Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: So basically what I've done now is to use the following command:

    sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:DB --username user --password pass --table DB.TABLE --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table table --hive-database default --as-parquetfile --compression-codec snappy --hive-overwrite --map-column-java 'COLUMN_NAME'=String

basically stopped trying to use the direct connector and used --map-column-java to get DATE columns into String format (not the best, but timestamp/date/whatever didn't work).  Don't know why --map-column-hive doesnt work

Comment: Still imports everything as a string now, which is weird.  But I can use sum(), and operators like >, <, = and it works correctly on the numbers.  I figure this could be multiple different things:
1.  Strings are stored in such a way as to work nicely with these operations (unexpectedly nice for me)
2.  It isn't actually storing them as strings (some sort of bug?)
3.  It is casting everything behind the scenes without telling me?  (which is probably terrible for performance)

I must be doing something different from others, since I don't see this exact problem being reported elsewhere.

Comment: I have the same problem with parquet file type e.g. if I keep my oracle NUMBER(10) as STRING in Hive then the sqoop import is working fine. But if I change the datatype to DECIMAL(10) I get and exception.